# проблема с сокетами на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я нашел простой мессенджер на python.Использую сокеты, и столкнулся с проблемой: отправлять сообщения можно только по очереди, т.е. пока я не отправлю сообщение, то другой человек не сможет мне ничего написать, потому что ожидает данных. Как можно решить эту проблему, мне не обязательная библиотека `socket`, если есть те либы, которые помогут мне избежать эту проблему, то тоже приветствуется. Не думаю что код будет полезен, но я оставлю его тут (хотя я просто скопипастил, как пример):

Клиент:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send(input(">"))
data = sock.recv(1024*1024)
sock.close()
print(data)
```

Сервер:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024*1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке кода `sock.listen(1)` Нужно увеличить аргумент с 1 до 5 например.

Так говорится в [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html):

> Наконец, аргумент для прослушивания сообщает библиотеке сокетов, что
> мы хотим, чтобы она поставила в очередь до 5 запросов на соединение
> (нормальный максимум), прежде чем отклонять внешние соединения. Если
> остальная часть кода написана правильно, этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: И это поможет? Или просто замечание

Comment: Это ответ на "отправлять сообщения можно только по очереди, т.е. пока я не отправлю сообщение, то другой человек не сможет мне ничего написать, потому что ожидает данных" в приведенном коде я не вижу ничего серьезного по работе клиента и сервера, мессенджером это можно назвать с большой натяжкой.

Comment: Какую тогда библиотеку использовать?

Comment: дело не в библитеке и эта сгодится, мессенджер подразумевает учет всех клиентов (как минимум двух) и рассылку им новых сообщений, тут же банальный пинг - понг, ничего более. Стоит поискать пример получше. (я не проверял этот пример, однако он внушает доверие и возможно сгодится в качестве образца https://gist.github.com/1995eaton/97db2d6e62bb58205778) перевести в python3 думаю проблем не составит